# Python QWidget Controls not Showing in a Form

Tags: python, user-interface, qthread, qwidget

I have a Main GUI class, and I am attempting to open another window, I am using QWidget to inherit from. The window that opens is just a progress bar and there is a QThread timer in another class in the Python file it uses to do a simpple countdown.

But my issue is that when I open the GuiProgressBar Window, none of the controls in the window show on the form for some reason.

This is from within my main GUI Class:

```
def TestOpenProgressWindow(self):
    myProgressBar = TimerThread.GuiProgressBar()
    myProgressBar.show()
    time.sleep(3)
    myProgressBar.StopProgressBar()
    myProgressBar.hide()
```

This is the code from within my GUIProgressBar class:

```
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    changeValue = Signal(int)
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.runs = False
        self.count = -1
        return

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while self.runs and (0 <= count < 10):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            count = count + 1
            self.changeValue.emit(count)
        self.finished.emit()

    def startThread(self):
        self.runs = True
        self.count = 0
        self.start()

    def stopThread(self):
        self.runs = False
        self.count = -1
        self.exit()


class GuiProgressBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btnStop = None
        self.btnStart = None
        self.label1 = None
        self.w1 = None
        self.barThread = WorkerThread()
        self.barThread.finished.connect(self.threadStopped)
        self.barThread.changeValue.connect(self.UpdateProgressBar)
        self.hprogress1 = None
        self.gui()
        self.StartProgressBar()

    def gui(self):
        self.w1 = self
        self.w1.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.w1.setWindowTitle("")
        self.w1.resize(320, 170)
        self.w1.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.w1.setToolTip("")
        self.label1 = QLabel(self.w1)
        self.label1.setText("Please wait while the BigQuery queries are run")
        self.label1.move(20, 20)
        self.label1.resize(290, 22)
        self.label1.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.label1.setToolTip("")
        self.hprogress1 = QProgressBar(self.w1)
        self.hprogress1.setMinimum(0)
        self.hprogress1.setMaximum(100)
        self.hprogress1.setValue(0)
        self.hprogress1.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.hprogress1.move(20, 50)
        self.hprogress1.resize(270, 22)
        self.hprogress1.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.hprogress1.setToolTip("")
        self.btnStart = QToolButton(self.w1)
        self.btnStart.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.btnStart.setText("Start")
        self.btnStart.move(20, 90)
        self.btnStart.resize(90, 22)
        self.btnStart.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.btnStart.setToolTip("")
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.StartProgressBar)
        self.btnStop = QToolButton(self.w1)
        self.btnStop.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.btnStop.setText("Stop")
        self.btnStop.move(110, 90)
        self.btnStop.resize(90, 22)
        self.btnStop.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.btnStop.setToolTip("")
        self.btnStop.clicked.connect(self.StopProgressBar)
        return self.w1

    def StartProgressBar(self):
        if not self.barThread.isRunning():
            print("Thread Started")
            self.barThread.startThread()
        else:
            print("Thread is already running")

    def StopProgressBar(self):
        if not self.barThread.isRunning():
            print("No thread is running")
        else:
            print("HERE")
            self.barThread.stopThread()
            print(self.barThread.isRunning())

    def threadStopped(self):
        print("Thread Stopped")

    def UpdateProgressBar(self, value):
        self.hprogress1.setValue(value)

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#    aw = GuiProgressBar()
#    aw.show()
#    sys.exit(app.exec())
```